# Line Detection with OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, edge-detection, c++, hough-transform

I'm trying to use the native functions of OpenCV *HoughLines* and *HoughLinesP* to detect the lines from an image. The *Canny* edge output of that image is the folllowing:

[image: Lines to detect]

The problem is that the OpenCV functions I mentioned above can't detect any of those lines. I have fiddled with the parameter values, trying to get a better result, but nothing. I think the issue may be that there are too many contiguous lines in the image, but is just a guess.

- Can anybody help me with this?
- And if the algorithm is not suited, can you point out an alternative?

**EDIT:**

I mainly lowered the [threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlines) value, but, unless I lowered it to much (case in which the returned image is fully covered with miss detected lines, i.e. the output image is a red rectangle), the output image is exactly the same as the input image, without any line detected. I also tried increase the angular resolution and use subpixel distance resolution, so instead of

`HoughLines( dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 100 );`

I tried something like

`HoughLines( dst, lines, 0.5, CV_PI/360, 20 );`

Without any success.

**EDIT II:**

Here is the code:

```
void showLines(Mat src){
    Mat dst, cdst, color_dst;
    // Image only have 9 pixels vertically, so it needs to be resized
    resize(src, src, Size(), 2, 2, INTER_CUBIC);
    //Canny -> generates the image above
    Canny(src, dst, 50, 200, 5, false);

    vector<Vec2f> lines;
    // detect lines
    HoughLines( dst, lines, 0.5, CV_PI/360, 20 );

    // draw lines
    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ ) {
        float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
        Point pt1, pt2;
        double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
        double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
        pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
        pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
        pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
        pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
        line( cdst, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
    }

    imshow("source", src);
    imshow("detected lines", cdst);

    waitKey();
}
```

The source (`src`) image is the following:

[image: source image]

Comment: Can you add some more detail eg. A couple of lines of code on which parameters you tried, or the resulting image after the failed line detection?

Comment: Adding the complete but minimal code would probably help people helping you.

Comment: It seems like HoughLines expects a binary input image, but "dst" output from Canny will be the same type as "src" which I'm guessing is not binary?

Comment: I don't think that's the case, because in the [example](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) provided in the documentation, "src" and "dst" are also of the same type (Mat)